# How to add account as principal to Elasticsearch access policy using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I'm trying this:

```
import * as elasticsearch from '@aws-cdk/aws-elasticsearch';
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
const config = { ... };
new elasticsearch.CfnDomain(config.stack, config.id, {
  accessPolicies: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": (new iam.AccountRootPrincipal).arn
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
    }]
  },
  ...
});
```

But now, after successful deploy, every time I run diff, I'm faced with this:

[image]

Not a big problem, but I'd like to have an ideal solution. Maybe use one of the iam classes to create the policy?

Comment: Looks like there is no cleaner way other than having a static string which represents the arn or as you mentioned creating IAM policy document. I tried using `PolicyDocument.fromJson()` and provided the json document where the principal is interpolated as `\`arn:aws:iam::${this.account}:root\``, the same thing happens. `Fn::Join` is used either way.

Comment: @dmahapatro well, the other constructs probably already solve this issue. I just wasn't able to locate one in their source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating CDK to **`1.31.0`** the problem was gone.